# Using a Magic Mug on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, writing-printing

A [Magic Mug](http://photo.walgreens.com/walgreens/pdpgifts/type=11oz_magic_mug_snapshot) is a coffee cup that has a picture behind a material that is black at room temperature. When hot water is added the black color turns transparent, revealing a picture or writing underneath.

[image: Sample Magic Mug]

What is the status of using such a mug on Shabbos? Is there an issue of writing or perhaps the changing of the coloring creates an issue?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like those Transitions (R) lenses that turn dark in the presence of UV rays. Ovadiya yosef says that making this transitions happen on Shabbos is permissible; it is not dyeing.

The fact that there is hidden writing behind the part that changes color is irrelevant.
See below for the source for the transitions.

http://www.halachayomit.co.il/EnglishDisplayRead.asp?readID=3384